# Given a pointer of node to be deleted in a linked list . how will you pass a pointer to the node in main function?

Tags: c, linked-list

Suppose I have a list [10 20 30 40 50 60]
I want to delete a node which has a data value 40, how would I pass the pointer of this node from `main()` function ?

I understand if I want to delete 10 the  I can simply pass head and if I want to delete 2nd node then i can pass head->next, but what if the list is so big and suppose I want to delete 70th node?

Comment: Traversal is only option to reach upto required node.

Comment: ^^ if you need to find nodes faster by data value, you should abandon the ll as a container - use a sorted list, tree or map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, whatever be the length, you have to take the approach,

- Start traversing the linked list nodes, starting from the head, one by one.
- Arrive at a particular node, check the data value.

  - if a match, update the pointer to next (previous) node(s).
  - if no match, move to next node.
- continue until you reach the leaf node.

Regarding passing the node, you can simply pass the pointer to the node to be freed up and deallocate the memory from the deletion function. before calling the deletion function, you need to make the required changes to re-align the list, without the to-be-deleted node.

Write the code, if you face any issues, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: I understand that we will have to traverse list to get the leaf to be deleted but that will be the case when you are passing the data value of the node. 
But I am asking when the data value is not given only the pointer of the node  is given.

Comment: @Chauhan if you have node count then loop upto that count for _temp = temp->next_; where _temp_ is assigned as _head_ before the loop and delete the _temp_

Comment: @Chauhan If you know the number of iteration, use that as the marker in the loop instead of comparing the values to get that node.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a pointer before the deleted pointer provided that it is a single-linked list.

For example the standard single-linked list `std::forward_list` in C++ has the following methods for removing a node

```
iterator erase_after(const_iterator position);
iterator erase_after(const_iterator position, const_iterator last);
```

The problem is that you have to update the node that precedes the deleted node. If the list is a single-linked list then nodes have only links to next nodes. They have no links to the preceding nodes.

Otherwise you have to find the passed pointer that to be deleted in the function traversing the entire list.

And there is no difference between

> if I want to delete 2nd node then i can pass head->next,

and

> if the list is so big and suppose I want to delete 70th node

Because the function does not know whether it is indeed the 2nd node or it is the 70th node.:)

But you can make your life easier if you will track a position in the list after a search operation.